# In Python, why can't you parse a file immediately after it is created using subprocess?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to read one input file (listed below as 'infile2', it can be any file), and for each line in this file, make File2, and then parse File2 to make File3.  Regardless of why I would want to code this way (unless it is the reason this is a problem of course...), why does the first block of code work, and the next fail?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess
#THIS WORKS
def CreateFile():
    command = "echo 'Here is some text' > CreateFile.txt"
    subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)

def Parse():
    with open("CreateFile.txt") as infile1:
        for line in infile1:
            return line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    infile2 = sys.argv[1]
    with open(infile2) as f:
        for line in f:
            CreateFile()

    with open(infile2) as g:       
            print Parse()
            outfile=open("CreateFile.txt",'w')
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess

def CreateFile():
    command = "echo 'Here is some text' > CreateFile.txt"
    subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)

def Parse():
    with open("CreateFile.txt") as infile1:
        for line in infile1:
            return line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    infile2 = sys.argv[1]
    with open(infile2) as f:
        for line in f:
            CreateFile()    
            print Parse()
            outfile=open("CreateFile.txt",'w')
```

The second block produces this error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CreateFile.txt'
Does the python interpreter not wait until the previous line is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Does the python interpreter not wait until the previous line is complete?

Not if the previous line is: `subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)`

`Popen()` creates an asynchronous process and immediately returns. If you want to wait for the process to complete, try [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call).

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) -

> Execute a child program in a new process.

Popen starts the process and continues the execution of the main thread. The issue you are seeeing is most probably because the command you issued using `Popen` has not yet finished by the time you are trying to open the `CreateFile.txt` . This is seen more prominently in the second script, because you are trying to open the `CreateFile.txt` right after issuing the command , whereas in the first script there are some statements inbetween those two actions.

Try using the [`.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method of Popen , to wait for the process to finish before executing the commands , Example -

```
def CreateFile():
    command = "echo 'Here is some text' > CreateFile.txt"
    subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True).wait()
```

---

Or you can also use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) if all you want to do is run the command (Would recommend this over Popen if your case is as simple as the code you posted) . From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) for that -

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

Example -

```
def CreateFile():
    command = "echo 'Here is some text' > CreateFile.txt"
    subprocess.call(command,shell=True)
```

Comment: Ah, this works now.  I thought time was the case also, but did not know how to test it specifically.  Good to know. Thanks! Sorry though, Rob was first...

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the file using `subprocess.Popen`, which starts a new process. After that the execution continues, and you're already trying to open a file that is being created.

You should wait for the subprocess to finish. You can do that with `.wait()` method of the `Popen` object.